# symfony3 entity generator yml bug

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I don't have a lot of experience with symfony or doctrine but I'm in a weird situation.

I got a simple User and Post entity. The thing is that Users can post things when they are logged.

The problem is that I wanted to link my table "post" and "user" with **post.user_id** and **user.id**

So with doctrine I decided to make a simple manyToOne relation in **Post** :

(Post.orm.yml)

```
Whatever\PostBundle\Entity\Post:
type: entity
table: post
repositoryClass: Whatever\PostBundle\Repository\PostRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    content:
        type: text
    userId:
        type: integer
        column: user_id
    createdAt:
        type: datetime
        column: created_at
manyToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: Whatever\UserBundle\Entity\User
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Entities generated and doctrine:schema:update done

Now I can get User informations with the posts as I wanted BUT ALSO can't post anything anymore because of user_id null

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO post (content,
>   user_id, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["content of the
>   post", null, "2017-04-21 11:27:04"]:

As you can see the user_id is null (I tried to set it manually in the controller, in the entity construct or with a form field, same result)

It's not over. Because if I comment/remove the part of Post.orm.yml :

```
manyToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: Whatever\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Then I can post again ... But I don't understand why.
(and btw I can't get users informations with the posts anymore. So I still need it)

Can someone give me an explanation ? I've been on this problem for 2 days. You're my last hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fields definitions, remove `userId`. Symfony will take care of that by your ManyToOne definition. See the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html) for reference.

```
Whatever\PostBundle\Entity\Post:
type: entity
table: post
repositoryClass: Whatever\PostBundle\Repository\PostRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    content:
        type: text
// Remove the next few lines
//    userId:
//        type: integer
//        column: user_id
    createdAt:
        type: datetime
        column: created_at
manyToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: Whatever\UserBundle\Entity\User
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: It looks like it solved the problem ! Thanks a lot ! I get it now.